# Data is not updated for two Pages in Parallel Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, realm

In my app I have two pages, one page shows the paerson information and another page shows the news information. I am using Realm database for local storage. I have used some mock data of persons and news, which will appear at the starting of the app. Now the problem is when I run my app, at first I click on person button and it is showing the person information, but if I click News button it is completely blank. nothing is shown on the window. Alterntively after uninstalling the app if I click news button at first, the news information is showing, but after clicking the person button, the person page is completely blank. The problem both pages are not updated simultaneously. I do not what would be the problem in this case.

I am giving my code in short

PersonPage Activity is

```
public class PersonPage extends AppCompatActivity implements PersonAdapter.PersonListListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PersonAdapter adapter;
private Realm personRealm;
private RealmResults<PersonModel> personResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);

    personRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.person_recycler);

    setUpRecycler();

    if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
        setRealmData();
    }
    showAllPersons();

}

private void showAllPersons() {
    personResult = personRealm.where(PersonModel.class).findAll();
    setAdapter(personResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setAdapter(RealmResults<PersonModel> results) {

    adapter = new PersonAdapter(this, personRealm.where(PersonModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private void setUpRecycler() {

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private void setRealmData(){

    List<PersonModel> colleague = new ArrayList<>();
    PersonModel model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(1+System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name1");
    model.setCompany("Comapny1");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    person.add(model);
    model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(2+System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Comapny2");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    person.add(model);

    for (PersonModel realmModel : person) {
            // Persist the colleague data
        colleagueRealm.beginTransaction();
        colleagueRealm.copyToRealm(realmModel);
        colleagueRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

    Prefs.with(this).setPreLoad(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (personRealm!= null)
        personRealm.close();
    super.onDestroy();
   }
}
```

My NewsPage Activity is

```
  public class NewsPage extends AppCompatActivity implements NewsAdapter.NewsChangeListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    private Realm newsRealm;
    private RealmResults<NewsModel> newsResult;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_page_layout);

        newsRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.news_recycler);

        setUpRecycler();

        if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
            setRealmData();
        }
        showAllNews();


    }
    private void showAllNews() {
        newsResult = newsRealm.where(NewsModel.class).findAll();
        setAdapter(newsResult);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setAdapter(RealmResults<NewsModel> results) {
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, newsRealm.where(NewsModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"),this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setUpRecycler() {

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);   
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private void setRealmData() {

        List<NewsModel> newsItem = new ArrayList<>();

        NewsModel model = new NewsModel();
        model.setId(1+System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setImage(R.drawable.image1);
        model.setTitle("Title1");
        model.setDate("01.02.2017");
        model.setDetail("Deatils1");
        newsItem.add(model);

        model = new NewsModel();
        model.setId(2+System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setImage(R.drawable.image2);
        model.setTitle("Title2");
        model.setDate("24.05.2017");
        model.setDetail("Deatils2");
        newsItem.add(model);


        for (NewsModel realmModel : newsItem) {
            // Persist the news data
            newsRealm.beginTransaction();
            newsRealm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
            newsRealm.commitTransaction();
        }

        Prefs.with(this).setPreLoad(true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (newsRealm!= null)
            newsRealm.close();
        super.onDestroy();
     }
   }
```

Comment: @EpicPanda is this question looks duplicate to the previous one

Comment: I answered this question on that question. You just didn't change `Prefs` to `initialData()` even though the answer said so in the edit, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509763/2413303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be  this statement.

```
if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
        setRealmData();
    }
```

Every time you load  your `Persons` list you are setting `getPreLoad` to `true`;

`Prefs.with(this).setPreLoad(true);`

When you load the `News` list it wont load the model from database because it will always get this statement `Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()` as `false`.

**EDIT:**

you can use different identifiers for `Person` and `News`. In your `Prefs` class create a seperate identifier for both and set them in their respective classes:

In your `Prefs` class add these methods:

```
public static void setPreLoadPerson(boolean shouldLoad) {

    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("loadperson", shouldLoad);
}

public static void setPreLoadNews(boolean shouldLoad) {

    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("loadNews", shouldLoad);
}

public static boolean getPreLoadPerson() {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("loadperson", false);
}
public static boolean getPreLoadNews() {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("loadNews", false);
}
```

Then in your respective classes `get` and `set` it according to you need.

PS : i wrote this code without any compiler so you might get some typo.

Comment: But if I remove this line, The data continues to looping. How can I make check that the data is loaded fror news and Person here

Comment: i edited my asnwer. You can try this aproach.

Comment: @M.Waqes But how can I declare two different identifier in same calss in this case. Because I need to create constructor in this case like public Prefs(Context context) {

        sharedPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

Comment: Thank you. it is working now. I have accepted your answer. But I have another question. may be not related to this question. Could you plaese explain me how can updated data inside setRealmData() method. I use this data as a mock database. I would like get all notification if I add some new data here or delete any data

Comment: I am sorry i am not that much familiar with `Realm` but from what i know you could use something like this :https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmChangeListener.html

Comment: For a working example have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889817/realmobject-changelistener

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
    setRealmData();
}
```

This code should be replaced by using `RealmConfiguration.Builder`'s `initialData(Realm.Transaction)` method.

```
public class InitialData implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<MyColleagueModel> colleague = new ArrayList<>();
        MyColleagueModel model = new MyColleagueModel();
        model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name1");
        model.setCompany("Comapny1");
        model.setTitle("Title1");
        colleague.add(model);

        model = new MyColleagueModel();
        model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name2");
        model.setCompany("Company2");
        model.setTitle("Title2");
        colleague.add(model);

        model = new MyColleagueModel();
        model.setId(3 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name3");
        model.setCompany("Comapny3");
        model.setTitle("Title3");
        colleague.add(model);


        for (MyColleagueModel realmModel : colleague) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof InitialData;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return InitialData.class.hashCode();
    }
}

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                      .deleteIfMigrationNeeded()
                      .initialData(new InitialData())
                      .build());
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I write it in my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509763/2413303

Comment: Shall I create two different class for news and person like this. this class contain the person information. but what would be the case for news. then how can I declare base application

Comment: Just replace `Prefs.with().preload` with `initialData`. What you need to write to db as initial data is what you'd add "on preload".

Comment: Yes. That is working for my colleague. But I also want to set data for news.in that case I need to create another class with initial data  then how can I declare  .initialData(new InitialData())

Comment: The initial data represents a single transaction, so just add the news in that same transaction.

Comment: .initialData(new InitialDataColleague())
.initialData(new InitialDataNews()) , something like this?

Comment: That clearly sets only the second one...

Comment: I have a question. In initial data I have set 4 data as pre data. But if I make any changes. for example if I add 2 new data. how can this app get notified about this changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151386/discussion-between-ktina-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: With the [Composite Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774028/2413303).

Comment: Sorry I could not understand. Is this the answer for new data update. Regarding the  .initialData(new InitialDataColleague()) .initialData(new InitialDataNews()) , I faced some problem. because it is loading only the second news data, not the colleague data

Comment: Well of course. You can only set 1 `initialData()`, so it makes sense to set an `InitialData` that wraps both initial data you mentioned using the composite pattern.